# How to Count the Total Number of Rows Across Multiple Tables stored procedure in c#

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

I have some tables. I just want to show it in a pay chart as a percentage. How many rows have a table? I try to count all rows and store them in a variable. I have a DTO model class. That class contains All the properties same Stored procedure variables. The results are exactly the same as our expected results. But when I try to invoke the stored procedure then shows an error. But when I Pass a single variable then it works well.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetTotalNumberOfFormsSubmitted]
    
AS
BEGIN

(select BurnOut = count(*) from Client_BurnOuts
UNION ALL
select CIP = count(*) from Client_CIPEnergyCrisises
UNION ALL
select HomeRepair = count(*) from Client_HomeRepairs
UNION ALL
select MadicalTravelAssistan = count(*) from Client_MedicalTravelAssistances
UNION ALL
select EmergencyAssistance = count(*) from Client_EmergencyAssistances
UNION ALL
select Heating = count(*) from Client_Heatings
UNION ALL
select DuckFoundation = count(*) from Client_DukeEnergyFoundations
UNION ALL
select FoodPantry = count(*) from Client_EmergencyFoodPantries
UNION ALL
select MedicalEquipment = count(*) from Client_MedicalEquipments)
END
```

Comment: Have you tried to execute your sql statement without the Procedure? That is not valid syntax.

Comment: Are you looking to return  one row with multiple columns? If so you can select the counts into variables and then at the end select all the variables.

Answer (score 0):

finally solved my problem,  that is my solution

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetTotalNumberOfFormsSubmitted]
    
AS
BEGIN
select
br.BurnOut, ho.HomeRepair, cip.CIPEnergyCrisises, mta.MadicalTravelAssistan, ea.EmergencyAssistance, he.Heating
 from
    (select BurnOut =  count(*) from Client_BurnOuts) as br,
     (select HomeRepair = count(*) from Client_HomeRepairs) as ho,
     (select CIPEnergyCrisises = count(*) from Client_CIPEnergyCrisises) as cip,
    (select MadicalTravelAssistan =  count(*) from Client_MedicalTravelAssistances) as mta,
    (select EmergencyAssistance =  count(*) from Client_EmergencyAssistances) ea,
    (select Heating =  count(*) from Client_Heatings) as he,
    (select DuckFoundation =  count(*) from Client_Heatings) as du,
    (select FoodPantry =  count(*) from Client_Heatings) as fp,
    (select MedicalEquipment =  count(*) from Client_Heatings) as me
END
```